# shared views between two WPF apps using MVVM light

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, mvvm-light

Using MVVM Light, I have two WPF applications that reference a common Views library. I also have a ViewModels library. The ViewModels library has a ViewModelLocator.

The dependencies are pretty simple: 
WPF apps -> Views -> ViewModels

The Views library has a ResourceDictionary and defines a ViewModelLocator resource for data binding at runtime and design time:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ViewModels;assembly=ViewModels">
    <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The problem is that when I go to set the DataContext at the top level element of my Views, I get an exception:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Views.WelcomeView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             DataContext="{Binding WelcomeViewModel, Source={DynamicResource Locator}}">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Exception:
A 'DynamicResourceExtension' cannot be set on the 'Source' property of type 'Binding'. A 'DynamicResourceExtension' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject

What am I doing wrong? Is defining the Locator in the Views as a resource even the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use`Source={DynamicResource Locator}` in your binding. If you use the `Source` property, you need to use a `StaticResource`

Comment: Ok - but I cannot get my static resource "Locator" to resolve. In App.xaml (in a regular WPF client) it works fine but in the Views class library project, with my ResourceDictionary.xaml, I cannot get it resolve. is there some trick I'm missing?

Comment: @kindohm Does your project run anyways? I frequently get XAML errors about StaticResources that can't get resolved, and just ignore them.

Comment: no it does not. I get a runtime error: {"Cannot find resource named 'Locator'. Resource names are case sensitive."}  My ResourceDictionary.xaml is set as "Page" build action. Just to be clear, I have an App.xaml defined in my WPF client with no resources, and a ResourceDictionary.xaml defined in my Views library. The views in the Views library cannot resolve the Locator defined in the ResourceDictionary.xaml

Comment: @kindohm Is your `Locator` a static class? Most `ViewModelLocators` I've seen have been static , and then you can bind `Source={x:Static local:MyViewModelLocator}`

Comment: minor detail, but just to clarify here - the static source must point to a property on the type, not the type itself, thus Source={x:Static local:Locator.Instance}. Thanks for your help!